# Count a particular value from list in Python mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, list, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am experimenting with Python with MongoDB. I am a newbie with python. Here I get records from a collection and based on a particular value from that collection, I find the count of that record(from the 1st collection). But my problem is I cannot append this count into my list.

Here is the code:

```
@gen.coroutine
def post(self):
    Sid = self.body['Sid']
    alpha = []
    test = db.student.find({"Sid": Sid})
    count = yield test.count()
    print(count)
    for document in (yield test.to_list(length=1000)):
        cursor = db.attendance.find({"StudentId": document.get('_id')})
        check = yield cursor.count()
        print(check)
        alpha.append(document)
    self.write(bson.json_util.dumps({"data": alpha}))
```

the displayed output alpha is from the first collection (student), the count value is from (attendance collection).

when I try to extend the list with check I end up with error

```
alpha.append(document.extend(check))
```

But I am getting the correct count value in python terminal, I am unable to write it along with the output.

My output is like
    `{"data": [{"Sid": "1", "Student Name": "Alex","_id": {"$oid": "..."}}, {"Sid": "1", "Student Name": "Alex","_id": {"$oid": "..."}}]}`

My output should be like

```
{"data": [{"Sid": "1", "Student Name": "Alex","_id": {"$oid": "..."},"count": "5"}, {"Sid": "1", "Student Name": "Alex","_id": {"$oid": "..."},"count": "3"}]}
```

Please guide me on how I can get my desired output.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach to this is to use the MongoDB [`.aggregate()`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.aggregate) method from the python driver you are using rather than repeated `.find()` and `.count()` operations:

```
db.attendance.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$StudentId",
        "name": { "$first": "$Student Name" },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

Then it is already done for you.

What your current code is doing is looking up the current student and returning a "count" of how many occurances there are. And you are doing that for every student by the content of your output.

Rather than do that the data is "aggregated" to return both the values from the document along with a "count" within the returned results, and it is aggregated per student.

This means you don't need to run a query for each student just to get the count. Instead you just call the database "once" and make it count all the students you need in one result.

If you need more that one student but not all students then you filter that with query conditions;

```
db.attendance.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "StudentId": { "$in": list_of_student_ids } } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$StudentId",
        "name": { "$first": "$Student Name" },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

And the selection along with the aggregation is done for you.

No need for looping code and lots of database request. The `.aggregate()` method and pipeline will do it for you.

Read the core documation on the [Aggregation Pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/).

Comment: can you please explain the above code I am finding it difficult to understand. My second collection does not have "student name", i use only the _id to match the values

Comment: I want only the count from the second collection "attendance".

Comment: @TonyRoczz Yes. But you are doing that "per student". What this means is you do not need to query every student and return the count. Read the relevant linked documentation and actually try running the query yourself, as that best explains the results. More explanation above.

Answer (score 0):

Add `count` entry to the dictionary `document` and append the dictionary:

```
for document in (yield test.to_list(length=1000)):
    cursor = db.attendance.find({"StudentId": document.get('_id')})
    check = yield cursor.count()
    document['count'] = check
    alpha.append(document)
```

Comment: Am getting a error " AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'extend' "
and when I use + it gives "dict object has no such operator"

Comment: the document becomes a list only after appending with alpha